# I can not parse html using xpath and lxml library

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xpath, lxml

I`m using Python 3.5.
I want to get a list of synonyms from the site, with the help of XPATH, but I do not get the required html code and get "[]".

```
import lxml.html
word=input("Input your word: ")
url = "http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/{word}?s=t.html".format(word=word)
html = lxml.html.parse(url)
syn = html.xpath("//DIV[@id='filters-0']")
print(syn)
```

If you are good at python, then tell me how to do such a task more concise and simple.
Big thanks!

Comment: What is the value of the word variable?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Paste a link & sample text to extract , Also your xpath is wrong .

Comment: Im trying to get synonyms from this site. In "word" variable is any word, for example "friend", "sun".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just imagining you need Synonyms extracted :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

source = html.fromstring(((requests.get('http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/wordy?s=t.html')).text).encode('utf-8'))
print (source.xpath('//div[@class="synonym-description"]//text()')[3].strip())
```

Comment: lxml can read directly from an url. Guessing the encoding is potentially wrong.

Comment: But it works only if you insert a word in a link, in code, but when you try to make the program enter a word and insert in a link construction "{word}". Format (word = word) " i get [<Element div at 0x11cc4a8>] instead of the normal answer. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for my bad English/

Comment: @Andrey Kazyncev it is important you make a HTTP request first & then parse from response . use requests library for making http requests & lxml.html for parsing from response .

Comment: @Daniel i use python 2.x which frequently raises encoding errors & requests lib is good for handling them right .

Answer (score 0):

The xpath-syntax is case sensitive:

```
syn = html.xpath("//div[@id='filters-0']")
print(syn)
```

Comment: As a result, I get [<Element div at 0x115c4a8>]

Comment: I do not know what to do